# Android phonegap login using local html and remote php

Tags: php, android, html, cordova, authentication

I got a HTML page inside my phone, that asks for the username and password. When the submit button get's pressed, it will check the database for an existing users using a PHP file that I uploaded on the server.

The problem is that, after the login success, how can I redirect from the PHP file to my main menu page that is a HTML file inside my phone?

In php, I saw this code that redirect it to other page,

> header("file:///android_asset/www/mainMenu.html");

I tried to change it, but it still isn't working. Can anyone help?

Comment: I think it should be header("Location: file://android_asset/www/mainMenu.html");

Comment: my bad, forgot about the location.. but still not working.. it gives me 500 error something..

Answer (score 2):

There is no way that the PHP header function can redirect to a local page stored on the device, because the pages on your local device are not hosted on a webserver and hence the remote webserver cannot address them using an http:// URL.

What you could do instead is have the PHP return a blank page that contains a snippet of JavaScript in the header which redirects the mobile browser to the local HTML file (file:///android_asset/your_file.html) using window.location.href or window.location.replace. This works because the JavaScript executes on the device and hence knows about files on the local file system.

EDIT: Your blank.html needs to look like this:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        window.location.href = 'file:///android_asset/my_local_page.html';
    </script>
</head>
<body>  
</body>
</html>
```

In the text above, replace my_local_page.html with your main menu page. Then put blank.html on your server and use PHP's header() to redirect to blank.html.

Comment: thank you sir.. at least i know there is a solution to this.. 
could you kindly share sample code to this.. i kinda new..
so, what i understand, in my php file that hosted in server which check for login, i need to put this, header("location:blank.php"), and inside the blank.php i have to put this code? "window.location.href = "file:///android_asset/www/mainMenu.html""

Comment: thanks for the example code.. but still, the application redirect me to the html file with blank page in web browser.. any idea?

Answer (score 1):

When building html5 + javascript app using phonegapp framework (or other webapp framework for mobil) i don't like to mix local and remote html page. The displayed pages are either fully local or remote, but no mix. When I choose to use a fully local display but need to call remote service, I use ajax requests.

I suggest you to do the same. So call your php login method using ajax, then change your phonegapp page on success. For example your php script can return a simple string which can either be 'succes' or 'fail'. You can then perform the necessary page change in your phonegap app.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

I like your suggestion of sticking to only local html files. I am also doing it the same way. But I have to implement payment gateway using local html. So the control goes to a remote server (I can't do it through ajax because there is no API available). Now how do I come back to my local folder. One solution is to send a page from server with payment parameters which in turn will call local html files through javascript. Can you suggest me any better way to do this?